Docker Hub service account login with scim
I am trying to setup a Docker Hub service account for our CI pipelines. Our organization is integrated with SSO and SCIM, and I am unable to login as the service account user because I do not have a login for that user using our IdP. Does anyone know the common way to solve this problem?
